# Linq Expression that compare Lambda result with a constant

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression

I have a calculated property

```
public decimal Avaibility
{
     get{ return l => l.Start - l.Uses.Sum(u => u.Amount);}
}
```

so i can't include this property in any predicate for linq to entities like

```
Products.Where(l => l.Avaibility> 0);
```

My current solution is repeat the lambda anywhere i need it but that is not maintainable, i want to reach something like

```
private Expression AvaibilityCalculation = l => l.Start - l.Uses.Sum(u => u.Amount);
public decimal Avaibility
{
    get{ return AvaibilityCalculation.Compile()(this/*product*/) ;}
}
public Product ProductsWithStock()
{
          //for l => l.Start - l.Uses.Sum(u => u.Amount) > 0
   return Products.Where(AvaibilityCalculation.GreaterThan(Expression.Constant(0, typeof(decimal))) );
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could recalculate your calculated value with every save and add it as an extra column to your table. If you are going to query it a lot this won't just make your linq statements easier to use, but it should perform better as well (calculate once).

Comment: I'm ok with my linq performance, what i need it is better easier to use and mantainability

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that returns your expression:

```
public Expression<Func<Product,bool>> AvailablityCompareTo
                                                  (bool greaterThan, int amount)
{
    if (greaterThan)
        return l => l.Start - l.Uses.Sum(u => u.Amount) >= amount;
    else
        return l => l.Start - l.Uses.Sum(u => u.Amount) <= amount;
}
```

usage:

```
Products.Where(AvailablityCompareTo(true,0))
```

It is a simple solution without expression voodoo, still a bit repetitive, but only inside the method.

Comment: It wasn't work in fact throw an exception because linq entities can't mapping MethodCallExpression that is what you are using in this case, beside this way i cant use the expression to calculate the Avaibility, thanks any way

Comment: Could you give some detail about how you use it? I use similar constructs with EF without problems. It gets translated to SQL.

Comment: Product.Where(p=> AvaibilityCalculation (p)> 0), remember that i also need the decimal value of AvaibilityCalculation for other purpose in the Avaibility property

Comment: You have to use the syntax `Where(AvailablityCompareTo(true,0))`. If you need the value elsewhere you can use a variable.

Comment: it will result on three line with the lambda 2 for you purposed method and another one for the Avaibility property, i need to specify the lambda l => l.Start - l.Uses.Sum(u => u.Amount) just one time to keep the maintanability on my code, this is a quality code problem

Comment: Maintainability is a valid concern. Personally I think that expression tree building is more error prone and less maintainable than two almost identical statements in one place. If the actual expressions are more complex or more parametrized you may have a point. Building expression trees would be more complex too though...